# How do I get my modem's IP address when using Google Wifi?

Tags: networking, router, modem, google-wifi

Occasionally I need to connect my ISP's modem directly to initiate a restart.

Normally when I connect to my modem directly, I can either connect to the modem using the vanity URL provided by the ISP, or I can figure out the modem's IP address, and connect to that (e.g. on macOS, option-click the network system menu icon, and observe the value for Router).

Problem is when I use Google Wifi as my router/access point, it's no longer easy to find the IP address of the modem. Now the menu item shows me the IP address of the Google Router, and accessing it goes to a page that explains how to manage the Google Router.

How do I find the IP address of the modem which the Google Router is connected to?

Comment: What is the make and model of the device Google provided?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure the best way, but one way to do it is to:

1. Launch Google Wifi app
2. Go to Settings Tab > Network & General > Advanced Networking > DNS
3. Under ISP's DNS, it may list your modem's local IP address

Comment: Why? This shows the ISP DNS for me (as it says), not the local IP address.